# ActiveRecord query to fetch all posts that have a topic in common with this post

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm racking my brain on this complex query for finding related posts:

Here're my models:

```
class Post
   has_many :post_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :topics, :through => :post_assignments
end

class PostAssignment
   belongs_to :post
   belongs_to :topic
end

class Topic
  has_many :post_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_assignments
end
```

Given that I have a post that may or may not have a topic. I need to find all posts that share a topic in common with this one.

I am already using the squeal gem so that syntax would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I haven't used the sequeal gem, so don't know its syntax. I think this would work, but it might not be the best way:

```
@post.topics.map(&:posts).flatten.uniq
```

Another way I can think of:

```
Post.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN post_assignments ON post_assignments.post_id = post.id LEFT OUTER JOIN topics on post_assignments.topic_id = topic.id').where(:topic_id => @post.topics.map(&:id))
```

Lastly, you could write the SQL.

Comment: it should be `.uniq` rather than `.uniq!`.
`.uniq!` returns `nil`

Comment: Yes this works as expected. I imagine that the first method has some performance drawbacks since it performs a query for each separate topic. 

The second method seems to have an error in the sql syntax. `AND LEFT OUTER JOIN` does not seem to be valid. I could never get it to work properly.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The 'AND' was extra.